# Path to uninstaller in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

During install, the installer creates a backup directory with a timestamp added to make it unique if installer is started multiple times. 
During uninstall I need to process some files (not placed by [Files] and [Dir] section) to be restored in the usUninstall or usPostUninstall. These files are placed in sub-directories in the backup directory.
For this, I need my location where the uninstaller is started so I can restore the files. 
I found and tried the GetCurrentDir function. But during uninstall the GetCurrentDir function returns the location c:\WINDOWS\system32.
I tested it also during install, but in that case the GetCurrentDir function returns the location where the installer is started.

How to get the proper location from where the uninstall is started?

Comment: I do not understand, how your (incorrect) use of `GetCurrentDir` goes with *"location where the uninstaller is started"*. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`{uninstallexe}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=uninstallexe) resolves to a path to the uninstaller.

If you combine that with [`ExtractFilePath`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extractfilepath), you get a path to the uninstaller folder:

```pascal
ExtractFilePath(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}'))
```

Though actually, the path will typically be the installation path. So you can use [`{app}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=app) directly.

---

Do not use `GetCurrentDir`! It returns the current working directory. What does not have to be the path to the installer.

Use [`{src}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src).

Comment: The {uninstallexe} is what I was looking for but didnot find. It solved my issue to knw which installer was started from what location.